# Creating a selective app on the iphone App Store

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I want to put an app on the app store that only members of my club can download.

Does apple support a way to do this?

I can easily make my app's homepage ask for a password to get to the sensitive features, but I'm afraid Apple won't support this because the general public might download my app and find it useless. It will truly only be useful to members of my club.

Will Apple reject the above scenario like I think it might? If so, what are my options?

Comment: The NameCheap and Linode apps only work for paying customers, I don't see what the problem with them is. The Telstra app only works for Telstra customers. Maybe you should read through the App Store terms and conditions, I think the only thing that can crop is if you take payments in the app external to using in-app purchases. If it's still problematic, you could try Enterprise Distribution.

Comment: So you are telling me that I can just have a page that asks for a password, and only if the password is correct, I go to the actual app, and that is ok. I just dont want to code everything and then get rejected and find out I wasted my time. Oh and enetrprise edition is not user friendly like the app store so I dont like it :)Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I think the App Store Review Guidelines you have to worry about are section 11 and item 2.22

Comment: Do you mean 22.2? And yeah, thanks, 11.1 is self-explanatory that I will be rejected I think, although it is under the purchases section.

Comment: 2.22 is about arbitrary restrictions, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Max said is a good answer, except that there are many apps that are intended for specific people. In fact, my app was indeed accepted by Apple and is currently on the App Store. It is password protected and only the 100 or so people who know the password can access the actual application. Apple is okay with this - my app was accepted within a week. But I do agree that if possible ad hoc distribution might be more suitable or easier in some cases.

Comment: I was under the impression that Apple don't look kindly on apps that require a login as soon as they're launched. Although it's not grounds for rejection I think it's best to release an app ad-hoc if it really is for a small subset of people.

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc distribution is your best bet. It will only allow distribution to devices that have been specified in the provisioning profile.

You can use something like [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com) to automate this process.

If you submit an app to the app store for public download which will only work for specified people, you will most likely be rejected.

Comment: This is not true. I have submitted apps to the app store that are restricted to certain users and they have gotten through without any issues. Apple have gone full circle on this policy (Review Guidelines 2.22) http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/09/apple-reverses-course-on-in-app-subscriptions/ Also testflight shouldn't be used for testing not distributing your apps to users for full distribution. Using testflight to distribute your apps to users that are not testers goes against there terms and conditions.

Comment: Can you cite in their terms and conditions where it prohibits this? It would surprise me if distributing ad-hoc to a small inhouse team would be against their conditions.

Comment: Its quite a long document that I am not reading through, but it basically says you are compliant with Apple iPhone Developer Program License Agreement and that under this Apps aren't allowed to be distributed through testflight to circumvent the Apple App Store. Testflight provides a service to allow developers to distribute apps to Beta Testers, not to get around having to go through the app store.